# How do I submit multiple models in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a JSP that allows users to dynamically create additional form fields to create multiple objects. Perhaps I want to allow users to be able to submit as many line items as they want when submitting an invoice form.

How do I create a Struts 2 Action that will be able to take in an `ArrayList` populated with objects created from those dynamically generated fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [Tabular input guide](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/tabular-inputs.html).

Answer (score 1):

[According to the (ever-poor) documentation](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html#indexing-a-collection-by-a-property-of-that-collection), which forces you to try to extrapolate the information you want, rather than just telling you authoritatively (and assuming you're really asking about Struts' built-in type conversion), your form fields would need to be named something like...

```
someList.makeNew(0).someField1
someList.makeNew(0).someField2
...
someList.makeNew(1).someField1
someList.makeNew(1).someField1
...
```

...and you would then need to [set up an ActionClassName-conversion.properties file](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html) to let the type converter know how to handle type conversion for fields which begin with `someList`.

The only time I actually tried this myself, I had trouble getting it working with `List`s and ended up having to use `Map`s.

Here's a useful blog entry about [modifying a `Map` of objects using type conversion](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/updating_a_list_of_domain_entities) - I haven't had much luck finding useful information about the `makeNew` field name format the documentation mentions, but this might help you get started.